# Doctrine find method render id as string

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

When I fetch an object by id with `find` method like

```
$manager->getRepository(Country::class)->find(1);
```

The given object look weird with a string Id instead int

```
Country {#41030 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: false
  -id: "1"
  -name: ""
}
```

But when I fetch the same country with `findOneBy`

```
$manager->getRepository(Country::class)->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);
```

I get the same object with the correct id type

```
Country {#41030 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: true
  -id: 1
  -name: "France"
}
```

If I try the `find` method with another entity, the returned object have an id with the correct type.

I try to find differences between this 2 entities without success

The weird return type is caused when I use `find` method in a Listener that use `LifecycleEventArg` `getEntityManager()` entity manager.

Do you alreay have a case like this ?

**EDIT**

There is the `Country` entity definition

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @DoctrineAssert\UniqueEntity("name")
 */
class Country
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(max=64)
     */
    private $name = '';

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->id.' - '.$this->name;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have same results if you execute this queries in a controller?

Comment: If i use `find` in a controller, the result is good

Comment: Can you add the definition of the Country entity? Or can you try accessing any method to load (Initialize) the object?

Comment: @MohammadZeinEddin Done

Comment: Mostly this is because the object is not initialized yet, and the types and properties is set after the initialization... an immediate dump of the object may be done before the initialization... try doing anything on the object before dumping, I  think this will set the properties and types...

Comment: When I try to use id getter method directly after the find I get a Typing error due because of the entity getter strict typing. But if I use name getter it works.

Comment: Got the same problem with an old laravel 5.1, update fixed the problem,  could not find where it come from, maybe from the same old dependency.